# PHP, Bitwise operation, not negative

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

When I trying to do this code in PHP:

```
$result = 4 << 29;
var_dump($result); // int(2147483648)
```

But in other languages, for example in JAVA or javascript it will be `-2147483648`.
Why?

Comment: Depends if you're on 32-bit or 64-bit PHP.... if 64-bit then `4<<29` will give a signed 64-bit integer with a value of `2147483648` because only bit 32 out of 64 will be set; if 32-bit then `4<<29` will give a signed 32-bit integer with a value of `-2147483648` because only the msb (sign bit) will be set

Comment: how it can truncate to 32 bit?

Comment: What do you mean `how it can truncate to 32 bit?`... A PHP integer is either 32-bit or 64-bit depending on whether you're using 32-bit or 64-bit PHP.... you can't simply change it from one to the other, PHP doesn't have 50 different integer datatypes, just one.... don't make assumptions about bit size, you can test it by checking the value of PHP_INT_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the PHP version you're running. A while ago there was a [bug in the 32-bit int math](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47092) when it comes to overflows. This has been solved in PHP 5.3.